# AWS CodeDeploy - Must be connected to a terminal

Tags: linux, bitbucket, cicd, aws-code-deploy

I have a CICD Bitbucket pipeline that runs and tries to execute a deployment script.

**appspec.yml**

```
version: 0.0
os: linux

    files:
      - source: scripts/osgi-deploy.sh
        destination: /home/jboss
        overwrite: true
    file_exists_behavior: OVERWRITE
    hooks:
      AfterInstall:
        - location: scripts/osgi-deploy.sh
          timeout: 180
          runas: jboss
```

**osgi-deploy.sh**

```
echo "about to deploy to osgi-app ($USER) ..."
screen -d -m -R "karaf" bash /home/jboss/scripts/build-start-osgi.sh &
```

**Output**

```
about to deploy to osgi-app (jboss) ...
Must be connected to a terminal.
```

As you can see, the `osgi-deploy.sh` file is executed and tries to start a `screen`, however because it is running from an external process (AWS CodeDeploy), it says it `Must be connected to a terminal`. If I run the `osgi-deploy.sh` from a CLI it works as expected.

I have tried to detach the screen using the `-d` parameter, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Richard, do you have to use `screen` or is an equivalent command okay?

Comment: I am using a `screen` because there's more than one application running on this server and also so that a user how logs in to the CLI can access the application.  Is there a better way?

Comment: Why can't you just run `bash /home/jboss/scripts/build-start-osgi.sh`? Does the process take a long time and you want it to keep running? What is the ultimate aim here? Excuse my naivety but I don't see how `AfterInstall` commands relate to users logging in?

Comment: the application runs on a Apache Karaf server, so the reason I want CodeDeploy to start the Karaf server in a `screen` is so that other users can then access the `screen` to see the Karaf server (e.g. from the running Karaf server a user can type `list`, `log:tail`, `logout`, etc to access its functionality). If it is not run in a `screen` and CodeDeploy just starts it, how can other users access the Karaf server?